# Re-sizing a webpage

Tags: sql, resize, mysqli, html

I'm a computer science student and I was given an assignment to create a whole website based on what we are given as a subject to do. I was meant to create a website about Google Glass and was meant to make the website re-sizable so it can open on mobile phones as well as display properly on other computer screens other then my own. I am looking for help on the re-sizing of the site as I'm stuck with re-sizing the SQL code, I would really appreciated the help if someone could show me an example of it.

> ```
> <html>
> ```
>
> Help
>
> ```
> <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
> <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
> <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
> <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
> <li><a href="Purchase.html">Purchase</a></li>    
> <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
> ```
>
> //Define some variables: $db_hostname = 'localhost'; 
>   $db_username='root'; $db_password=''; $db_database='glass';
>
> //Connect to MySQL $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname,
>   $db_username, $db_password );
>
> //Check there is no error connecting if (!$db_server) die("Unable to
>   connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
>
> //…Next step is… 2. Select the database! mysql_select_db($db_database)
>   or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
>
> //Create a SQL query $query = "SELECT * FROM help";
>
> //Run the query $result = mysql_query($query); if (!$result) die
>   ("Unable to run the query" . mysql_error());
>
> //Step 5: Output results. /*Count number of rows returned from the
>   query and assign to a variable*/ $number_rows =
>   mysql_num_rows($result);   //Run a loop to output data for all rows
>   echo '
>
>   '; for ($i=0; $i';     echo '';    echo '' . mysql_result($result, $i,
>     'headline') . '
>   ';     echo '';   }   echo
>     '
>
> ';   //Step 6: Close connection to MySQL mysql_close();
>
> ?>
>
> Copyright 2012. ©

Comment: What do you mean by "*re-sizing the SQL code*"? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to re-size SQL like html, I'm only looking for an example as I want to learn how to do it my self. I don't think its possible but how would you go about making a website responsive when its made out of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your asking 2 questions. Im not gonna do your assignment, but i will push you in the right direction :)

Firstly, theres no such thing as "re-sizing SQL code", unless you mean making code more efficient by eliminating lines. Also, the code youve posted is **mysql**, (deprecated unfortunately). you use **mysqli**. [example is found here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

The bottomline for using php to connect to a sql database:

```
<?php
  //connect
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

  //execute query
  $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  //loop through results
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['myColumn'];
  }

  //disconnect
  mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Secondly, a webpage layout that is viewable on different resolutions is called a "fluid" or "responsive" layout. below is an example of fluid - which means you specify `width` of elements in `%`, instead of `px`:

```
<style>
.header{
  height:120px;
  width:100%;
}
.content{
  margin:auto;
  width:80%; 
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</body>
```

In the future, please make an effort to attempt the solution, instead of just asking StackOverflow to give you assignments, cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wasn't looking for anyone to do it for me I just wanted an example so I could learn how to do it but like you said it's not possible. My question was "IS THERE A WAY TO DO IT" (create a responsive site out of SQL code)

Comment: no worries. you probably dont care anymore, but just to clarify - sql doesn't create the webpages, which is why its impossible. html creates the webpages - sql gets data to DISPLAY on the webpage. 2 very different languages which achieve 2 very different things :)